# Handling The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#

I have a custom HTTP class I made for my application. It's just basic, the application is fairly simple. Anyway, sometimes the post method will return the following error:

```
Handling The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

My method is

```
public String post(String url, String postData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = this.userAgent;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.CookieContainer = this.cookieJar;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

        String source = reader.ReadToEnd();

        return source;
    }
```

I'm sending a request to update my Facebook status. Most of the time it works, the odd occasion it doesn't and throws an exception.

What's the best way to catch this exception so I can retry the request?

Comment: Debug the method.  You need the exception message and stack trace if you want to resolve this.  Add a try/catch and log the exception information.

Comment: Amy, how can I handle the exception though to retry it? If I catch it, then what? Do I retry again? What if I want to retry the request 3 times? I think this is just an issue with Facebook servers responding wrong because 99% of the time it works.

Comment: Are you sure the exception occurs here?  Just asking because `HttpWebResponse` contains a `StatusCode`, I'm thinking that the error is more a failure to react properly to the fact that the `StatusCode` wasn't `HttpStatusCode.OK` somewhere down the line...

Comment: I know what the error was. Fixed it, it was an application issue. Would still like to know the best way to handle HTTP errors that are beyond my control as these often happen when I develop web scrapers. I tend to catch and ignore, but I don't want to be doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be wise to repeat the request.  There are instances where a request fails to return but the receiving server may have processed it, as a result, a retry would result in duplication.

It would be better if you raised an error response from this post method - By raising a specific exception - then it is the responsibility of the calling method on deciding what to do.

It may choose to repeat the request or ignore it or try to validate it was received before attempting to send again.

Comment: Sounds logic. I'll give that a try.